# Cached version of the endpoint in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to have alternative urls for my API endpoints that would use nginx caching. For example a url `/cached/api/songs/latest` should return a cached version of the endpoint `/api/songs/latest` coming from the PHP engine.

I came up with this configuration but it does not work. Could you please advise what am I doing wrong?

```
proxy_cache_path /data/cache/nginx keys_zone=one:10m loader_threshold=300
                     loader_files=200 max_size=200m;

server {
        server_name api.myserver.com;

        # SSL configuration
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate ...
        ssl_certificate_key ...

        root /data/myapp/public;
        index index.html index.php;

        # cached version of the endpoints
        location ~ ^/cached/.*$ {
                rewrite ^/cached(.*)$ /$1  break;
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:443;
                proxy_cache_valid any 60m;
        }

        # standard includes
        include global/restrictions.conf;
        include global/common_php.conf;
        include global/static_assets.conf;

}
```